# Using jQuery ajax response data

Tags: jquery

I am using ajax post and am receiving data in the form of html. I need to split up the data and place pieces of the data all over the page. I built my response data to be something like `<p id='greeting'> Hello there and Welcome </p> <p id='something'>First timer visiting our site eh'</p>` It is a little more complicated and dynamic but I can figure it out if get this question answered. Thanks

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'confirm.php',
            data: "really=yes&sure=yes",
            success:function(data){
                    //Need to split data here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: Just realized you should probably do this:

```
success:function(data) {
    data = $('<div/>').append(data);
    $('#greeting',data).appendTo('#one')
    $('#something',data).appendTo('#two')
}
```

As you cant use `.find` properly since it isnt a child but if you append it to an empty node you can. The other alternative would be using `.filter`

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'confirm.php',
            data: "really=yes&sure=yes",
            success:function(data){
                    $('#greeting',data).appendTo('#one')
                    $('#something',data).appendTo('#two')
            }
        });
```

You can extract from `data` and append where you want to. You can also do something like return JSON instead, and instead of extracting html from html just access the html from an object.

```
$(data.greeting).appendTo('#one')
$(data.something).appendTo('#two')
```

The response would have to be like:

```
({ 'greeting':'html', 'something' :'other html' })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for some reason I cannot just grab one tag via id. If it works I grab the entire string.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the JSON solution?

Comment: basically, return JSON from server-side which is a string parsed as Javascript. `json_encode` if you're using php will help. `dataType:'json'` will be needed as well on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you string the answers together within `confirm.php` with the `|` character, then when the string gets returned as the variable data you can split it with `datas = data.split("|")` and access the individual answers with `data[0]`, `data[1]`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

(Meder's response will work if you are comfortable with JSON, but regular expressions are probably a little easier and will work just as well for this.)

You will probably need to break up the response text using regular expressions. For example, if the response text is:

```
<p id='greeting'> Hello there and Welcome </p>
<p id='something'>First timer visiting our site eh'</p>
```

Then you could use some JavaScript like this:

```
var greeting = response_text.match(/<p id='greeting'>.*</p>/);
var something = response_text.match(/<p id='something'>.*</p>);
```

(This site is great for learning about regular expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: 1. My answer isn't specific to JSON, the JSON was an alternative tip 2. You should *never* use regular expressions to parse html. Only a matter of time before it's prone to failure - jQuery internally parses and grabs with DOM methods which is what you should be doing

Comment: Take a look at Coding Horror's take on regex and HTML:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

As they would say, regex and html is a bad idea, but not always. For example, if you were just inserting a welcome message into a couple places after the user logged in (for example, "Welcome, Theopile"), then it doesn't seem like a couple lines of regex is such a big crime.

To the OP - If you have something significantly more complicated than what you example is or if any part of the AJAX response is determined by the user, then Meder is completely right.

Comment: Also, for some reason I can't add a comment to Meder's solution, but if you are using PHP, this site has a great example of using JSON:

http://www.extjs.com/learn/Tutorial:Creating_JSON_Data_in_PHP